# Is there a way to pull data from a lot of one-to-many tables in one call with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, one-to-many

Using MySQL 5.7, I have a `movie` table that has many single value fields:

```
+--------------+--------------+
| Field        | Type         |
+--------------+--------------+
| id           | int(11)      |
| title        | varchar(255) |
| release_year | int(11)      | 
| rating       | int(11)      |
+--------------+--------------+
```

When I call a query on that table, like `SELECT * FROM movie WHERE id = 5` it will return just one row with each column's data, as expected.

I have a number of tables with one-to-many relationships with that `movie` table. I've got `movie_subtitle`, `movie_language`, `movie_actor`, etc. Here is one for example:

```
+--------------+--------------+
| Field        | Type         |
+--------------+--------------+
| id           | int(11)      |
| movie_id     | int(11)      |
| subtitle     | varchar(255) | 
+--------------+--------------+
```

My issue is that in order for me to get all of the field data for one single movie, it seems I need to make about 10 `SELECT` calls. One for the `movie` table, and then one for each of the addition add-on tables.

If a user has 1,000 movies, this quickly can turn into 10,000 `SELECT` calls, if I am trying to run a larger query against an entire collection.

Is there a way to make this all output in *one* call? Or is this just the way it's supposed to be? I feel like there is a better way to do this and I'm just not educated enough about database relationships to understand what I am missing here.

I need to pass the data I receive from these calls to my PHP page to put it into JSON.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use joins to group the data together? Without a table structure, sample data (sql fiddle perhaps) and knowing what you want out as a sample, people here would just be guessing.

Comment: I would suggest either joining the data together or perform multiple queries pulling extra data out that you can coalesce later in php. In the case of joins, it works great but you typically end up with duplicate data in your return result and you would have to ignore a bunch of it or depending on your output you can also group_concat data together into a single column. With the multiple queries, it offers little to no benefit for only one record, but with multiple records, your number of queries doesn't increase.

Comment: `JOIN` brings back many rows with the same data except for the one column... for example: The movie Goonies will bring back three rows, all with the same data, expect the `genre` column in each row will be Adventure, Comedy, and Family. Just looking for a way to avoid that.

Comment: So you could use a group_concat to turn the join into a single comma separated field with the join. Or you could query for all the movies, loop over in php and get a unique list of ids and then go query for all the genres `where movie_id in (1, 2, 3...etc movie ids)` (or where genre.id in unique list from movies). Then your query gets longer (list of ids) with more movies, but you still only run one query. You can also use a sub-query for the `in` list like `where genre.id in (select genre_id from movies where user_id=1234)`

Comment: If you had a simple sql fiddle with some sample data, I could write a few to show you what I mean.

Comment: I am going to avoid `GROUP_CONCAT`, but I'll consider your PHP loop. It would be only 10 queries or so regardless of how many records I'd need, so that may work for me. I'll consider it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing multiple queries and coalescing the data in php. Here is a simple example for movies and genres:

Sample tables:

```
Table: MOVIES
    id, title, release_year, rating ...etc

Table: MOVIES_GENRES (many-to-many relation to movies and genres)
    movie_id, genre_id

Table: GENRES
    id, name, description

Table: USERS_MOVIES (many-to-many relation to users and movies)
    user_id, movie_id
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
//example user id
$user_id = 5;

//query for all movies
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `movies` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `movie_id` FROM `users_movies` WHERE `user_id`={$user_id})";

$result = /*perform query*/;

//loop over the result
$movies = array();
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    //add the row to the movies array with the movie id as the key
    $movies[$row['ID']] = $row;

    //also add an empty genre array in anticipation of genre data being coalesced
    $movies['genres'] = array();
}

//get a comma separated list of all the movie ids for use in queries below
$movieIDs = implode(',', array_keys($movies));

//now query out genre based on movies, make sure to get the movie_id for coalesce
$sql = "SELECT `movie_id`, `name`, `description` FROM `genres` JOIN `movies_genres` ON `genre_id`=`genres`.`id` WHERE `movie_id` IN ({$movieIDs})";

$result = /*perform query*/;

//loop over the result
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    //add the genre to this movie
    $movies[$row['movie_id']]['genres'][] = $row;
}
```

In this whole thing, I only use two queries regardless of how many movies. I just generate a list of all the movie ids and use that in subsequent queries. Then coalesce the data back together in php. Later down the line I can loop over the `$movies` array and use that to build a table or whatever I need. In the genre query, you can also include a join (or sub-query) to `users_movies` on the `movie_id` and then don't need a large `IN` list, but can use the user_id from above.